# Have links to items on Steam posted in chat expand like Wikipedia links do

Tags: feature-request, chat

When posting a link in chat, some websites will expand the link into details from the destination.  Examples of links that do this are site such as:

- Youtube
- Wikipedia
- xkcd
- Stack Exchange sites

For Arqade, I think it would be nice to also include `http://store.steampowered.com/app/...` links in this list of sites that are oneboxed.  It could work similar to Wikipedia links by taking information from the box at the top right of a page:

[image: Example store page]

Here is my example of what it could look like compared with how the Wikipedia links expand.  I am in no way a designer so if you can make a better looking suggestion feel free to share it.

[image: Wikipedia link]

[image: Example Steam]

Comment: PFFFFFFFT. Like I would ever post a link to the store page for TF2.

Comment: I like this idea, but given it's for chat I can't see it getting implemented anytime soon (if at all). One of the chat regulars might be able to whip up a browser plug-in that could do it (cc @fredley). In terms of design, I'd drop the list of tags and user reviews, and add in the price.

Comment: @Wipqozn How does that look?

Comment: @Batophobia I like that much better than your original design. A lot less cluttered.